# How to remove certain characters from a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My current string is "Spam, Eggs ( S & E)".

In our data base people are being input as: "First, Last" sometimes people add nicknames in the form of ("Nickname") so an example string would be "William, Smith (Will)" No matter the case I only want the first and last.

Is there a quick solution to this?

Comment: Based on what criteria are you removing `( S & E)`? Is that "everything after the 2nd space"? Or is it "everything in parentheses"? Or "everything after the 10th character"? Or one of the other infinite possibilities?

Comment: "I will have multiple strings but the idea is the same." What is the idea?

Comment: If you had more samples listed it would be much easier for anyone to help you.

Comment: In our data base people are being input as:
"First, Last" sometimes people add nicknames in the form of ("Nickname")

so an example string would be
"First, Last (Nickname)"

No matter the case I only want the first and last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

string1 = "Spam, Eggs ( S & E)"
string2 = re.sub(r'\(.*\)', "", string1).strip()
print(string2)
```

Results in the output you want. Repl Here:

https://repl.it/repls/UselessColorlessArchitect

The regex matches an opening parenthesis followed by any character (any amount of times) followed by a closing parenthesis.

Comment: this leaves a trailing space. Maybe something like `r'\s*\(.*\)'`?

Comment: This leaves a trailing space in the result string, You could try removing that as part of the `re.sub()` or strip the result string.